# Converting an NSValue back to the struct type that was stored in it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, chipmunk, nsvalue

I'm storing Chipmunk Physics' `cpShape` objects in an `NSMutableDictionary` by way of `NSValue` objects and the following lines of code:

```
NSValue *shapeValue = [[NSValue alloc] initWithBytes: shape objCType: @encode(cpShape)];
[staticBodiesInUse setObject: shapeValue forKey: name];
```

I now need to get the `cpShape` back out, to compare it to another shape. How can I do that? I see a `getValue:` method in `NSValue` but it needs a buffer, not too sure what to do with it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So the answer by trojanfoe is only partly correct.

There is a *huge* problem with doing that. When you create the `NSValue` that way, you are copying the `cpShape` struct, and getting it back out, you are copying it again. `cpShape` structs are pretty much exclusively used by reference. Each time you copy it, you get a new reference to the new copy, and some of those copies exist on the stack and get destroyed silently and automatically. Very very bad.

Instead you want to create a `NSValue` using `[NSValue valueWithPointer:shape]` and get that pointer back using `[value pointerValue]`. This way the NSValue is only storing a pointer to the original `cpShape`.

Comment: And using a `cpShape *` is *problem free*?  I don't think so and will lead to insidious bugs unless used very carefully.

Comment: @slembcke can you elaborate a bit more on why creating a copy of the struct in the current stack frame is bad (or worse than passing around pointers to the struct)? Or is that due to the way chipmunk operates?

Answer (score 8):

Isn't it simply:

```
NSValue *value = [staticBodiesInUse objectForKey:name];
cpShape shape;
[value getValue:&shape];
```

Comment: It would appear so, yes. I missed the class on referencing, clearly ;)